# I am trying to understand a certain proof of Catalan numbers and I do not understand a math behind one part

Tags: algebra-precalculus, proof-explanation, binomial-coefficients, factorial, catalan-numbers

The proof got that
$$
\frac{1}{k+1}\frac{(2k)!}{(k!)^2}=\frac{1}{k+1}{2k \choose k}
$$
Which indeed is the formula for Catalan numbers but I do not understand how:
$$
\frac{(2k!)}{(k!)^2}={2k \choose k}
$$

Thanks for help in advance.

Comment: ${2k \choose k}= \frac{(2k)!}{k! \cdot k!}.$

Answer (score 4):

You can apply the definition of binomial coefficients $\binom{n}{\ell}$ with $n=2k$ and $\ell=k$:

\begin{equation*}
\binom{n}{\ell}=\frac{n!}{\ell!(n-\ell)!}=\frac{(2k)!}{k!(2k-k)!}=\frac{(2k)!}{k!k!}.
\end{equation*}

Best

Comment: Thank you I just got it! Have a great day :)

Answer (score 2):

It follows because

$${2k\choose k}=\dfrac{2k!}{k! (2k-k)!}=\dfrac{2k!}{k!\times k!}.
$$

Comment: Thank you I just got it! Have a great day :)